# char * disappears if I don't print it?

Tags: c, string, return

I have a very odd problem here. I basically have a function which takes in a `char*` and it splits the string and returns the substring. My problem is if I print length of the `char*` THEN return it then the value remains but if I don't call the function to get the length then when it comes out of the function it disappears.

I've probably explained it poorly above so I'll copy and paste segments of the code below:

```
void processFile (char *currentLine, int currentLineNumber)
{
    int     type;

    char    *accountName, *secCodeRef, *secCode = NULL, *reference = NULL;

    if ((type = getType(currentLine)) == TYPE_HEADER)
    {
        accountName = strtok (currentLine, " "); //Remove "Type"

        accountName = strtok (NULL, " ");   //Get Account Name
        secCodeRef = strtok (NULL, " ");    //get Security code and reference
        secCode = getSecCode(secCodeRef, secCode); //Get Security Code
        printf("TEST:%s\n", secCode);

    }
```

Basically `secCodeRef` is a string that contains **both** the security code and the reference (.e.g.) GB0007980592REFERENCE1. The first 11 characters are the security code and the rest is the reference. So I pass this string into a function called `getSecCode`: (`SECCODELENGTH` is 13 btw)

```
char *getSecCode (char *secCodeRef, char *secCode)
{
    char        SecCode[SECCODELENGTH];
    char        *SecuCode = (char*)&SecCode;

    memcpy(SecCode, &secCodeRef[START], SECCODELENGTH-1);

    SecCode[SECCODELENGTH-1] = '\0';

    printf("%d\n", getStringLength(SecuCode));

    return SecuCode;

}
```

It extracts `SecuCode` ok when this line runs:

```
printf(%d\n, getStringLength(SecuCode));
```

The result is: (I'm reading from a file btw with different data in it)

```
12
TEST:GB0007980592
12
TEST:GB0007980593
12
TEST:GB0007980594
```

Which is correct

But when I comment out:

```
//printf(%d\n, getStringLength(SecuCode));
```

The output is:

```
TEST:
TEST:
TEST:
```

Why does the print statement affect the return value at all?

Comment: Please avoid using many identical names. It is very confusing. And use `char *SecuCode = (char*)&SecCode;` instead of `char *SecuCode = SecCode;`. It won't solve your problem though.

Comment: I didn't do what you said I did. Thanks for the naming advice though.

Comment: Please don't write `char` as `Char`. They're two different identifiers. (I've edited your question.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry I didn't realise they are different. I only really know C and (to a lesser extent) Java.

Comment: Both C and Java are case-sensitive.

Comment: @KeithThompson Since it was the title to a question, I didn't think it mattered. Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 char        SecCode[SECCODELENGTH];
 char        *SecuCode = (char*)&SecCode;
```

`SecCode` is a local array to function `getSecCode()` and you return the address of this local array which will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah yes I see, I will move SecCode[SECCODELENGTH] to the first function and see what happens. Why does it work if I call the print statement though?

Comment: @NazHaque When you have undefined behavior in your code anything might happen. Luckily it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn;t

Comment: Thank you very much Gopi, I would've never seen it if you hadn't pointed it out.

Comment: @NazHaque no probs.. :)